# GMail-API (Python) EMail Sent To Self - By Passes Inbox

Tags: python, gmail-api

If I use GMail and send a message to myself it appears unread in my inbox.

If I send a message via the GMail API using a python script, the message is sent up it only appears in "All Mail" and "Sent" and is marked as read.

I have checked my filters and there is nothing there that would be doing this (and I would expect filters to apply consistently across both of the above use-cases).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of those "Google" things.
Waited an hour - no changes to the code but the behaviour is now as expected !